# Languages shown in AppStore

Tags: ios, app-store

I have an app submitted to the app-store and to my surprise when it hit the app-store it showed the app was available in: English, Chinese, Dutch, French, German, Romanian, Russian, Spanish. While I did absolutely nothing with localizations, the Germans commented that the app was only in English (which is true).

Does anybody know why I get these languages?

I know that it should be stored in the bundle somewhere.

In the Info.plist the value of CFBundleDevelopmentRegion is en_US. And that is the only thing language related I can find in my project (no .lproj files are present).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check localisations in your project:

[image: Xcode]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I only looked in my target, as I have different target for different languages, never thought about looking in the project.